# How/where do I add $('#fullpage').fullpage() code?

Tags: 8, javascript

I want use the [fullpage library](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs). In my theme.libraries.yml file, I added theses lines.

```
fullPage:
  header: true
  js:
    js/fullPage.js/jquery.fullPage.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

jquery.js and jquery.fullPage.js are now present in the `<head>` tag, 
but to run fullpage.js, I must execute [this additional script[2](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

How and where do I add this little script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a javascript file in your theme and attach it to pages as shown in the documentation.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Make sure you theme library has a dependency on fullPage.